# Making and appending into new lists with loops

Tags: python, arrays, string, list

I've been trying to make  a program to look at the first x numbers of a list, sort them in ascending order, then look at the next x-1 numbers and sort them in descending order, all the way until x = 1

I've tried this program but I am very stuck and unsure of how the logic of this problem should be.

```
n = [3, 14, 1, 59, 26, 535, 8, 97, 932, 38, 462, 64, 3, 3, 83, 279, 50, 288, 4, 19, 716, 939, 9, 37510]

l = []
count = 0
for i in n:
  count += 1
print(count)

length = 6
for i in range(1, count):
        l = (n[::length])
        length = length - 1
print(l)
```

It only returned the first and last of the list.

Comment: "It only returned the first and last of the list." What should the output be for this input? Can you show the reasoning? Can you explain, in plain English words, the steps that should be taken, one at a time, inside the loop? Also: what do you expect `n[::length]` to do, and how does this relate to solving the problem? If you do assign a list to `l` like `l = ...`, and `l` was already the name of a list (like `[]` at the start of the program), what are you expecting to happen to the old list? Why?

Comment: "I've been trying to make a program to look at the first x numbers of a list" What is `x`, and how does it relate to the length of the list?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Sorry! I put x as in it is a variable in my question, so it can change. In this case, it is length.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel the output should be 1 3 14 26 59 535 932 462 97 38 8 3 3 64 83 288 279 50 4 19 716 9 939 37510

Comment: Oh, I see now - you mean the variable named `length` in your program, not the length of the list. So, we sort the first 6 numbers in ascending order, going from  `[3, 14, 1, 59, 26, 535]` to `[1, 3, 14, 26, 59, 535]`; then the next 5 in descending order, etc.? Okay, so try to take the problem a step at a time. Can you write code that gets the first 6 numbers from the list? Can you write code to sort them? After you sort them, what should be done with them in order to make progress towards the final goal?

Comment: I hope you get the idea - this is *not a discussion forum*, so I can't just talk through the whole problem with you. This is just to give you a sense of how to analyze the problem. If you get stuck somewhere, you will at least have a properly *specific* question which you can then ask, per [ask]. ([Please try to look for an existing answer first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), though.)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a while loop:

```
def split_list(nums: list[int], size: int) -> list[list[int]]:
    """
    Splits list into sorted sublists of decreasing sizes
    alternating between ascending and descending until size < 1.
    """
    result = []
    i = 0
    ascending = True
    while i + size < len(nums) and size >= 1:
        result.append(
            sorted(nums[i:i + size])
            if ascending
            else sorted(nums[i:i + size], reverse=True)
        )
        i += size
        size -= 1
        ascending = not ascending
    if i < len(nums):
        result.append(
            sorted(nums[i:])
            if ascending
            else sorted(nums[i:], reverse=True)
        )
    return result


nums = [
    3, 14, 1, 59, 26, 535, 8, 97, 932, 38, 462, 64, 3, 3, 83, 279, 50, 288, 4,
    19, 716, 939, 9, 37510
]
print(f'{nums = }')
print(f'{split_list(nums, size=4) = }')
print(f'{split_list(nums, size=10) = }')
print(f'{split_list(nums, size=7) = }')
```

**Output:**

```
nums = [3, 14, 1, 59, 26, 535, 8, 97, 932, 38, 462, 64, 3, 3, 83, 279, 50, 288, 4, 19, 716, 939, 9, 37510]
split_list(nums, size=4) = [[1, 3, 14, 59], [535, 26, 8], [97, 932], [38], [3, 3, 4, 9, 19, 50, 64, 83, 279, 288, 462, 716, 939, 37510]]
split_list(nums, size=10) = [[1, 3, 8, 14, 26, 38, 59, 97, 535, 932], [462, 288, 279, 83, 64, 50, 4, 3, 3], [9, 19, 716, 939, 37510]]
split_list(nums, size=7) = [[1, 3, 8, 14, 26, 59, 535], [932, 462, 97, 64, 38, 3], [3, 50, 83, 279, 288], [939, 716, 19, 4], [9, 37510]]
```